# How to display multiple row records of similar ID's in single row?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables user and work. Work table has multiple user's work experience.I have to retrieve most recent 2 companies on the basis of start date.

**Conditions :**

1.If Work Table has multiple user's Id's records, retrieve recent 2 records and show in single row (e.g. User_id = 1)

2.If Work Table has single record is most recent companies record and second record should be "NULL"(e.g. user_id = 3).

```
    user
    user_id  First_name  Last_name
      1        AAA         BBB
      2        PPP         QQQ
      3        SSS         RRR

    work
    user_id recent_company position start_year end_year
        1        ABC          CCC     2014       2015
        1        PQR          DDD     2013       2014
        1        MNO          EEE     2012       2013
        1        MNO          EEE     0000       0000
        2        XYZ          TTT     2008       2009
        2        IJK          MMM     2005       2008
        3        QRS          ZZZ     2001       2002
```

I've tried for most recent company record 1 :

```
select u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name,uw.recent_company1,uw.position1,uw.start_year,uw.end_year from muser u
left join
(SELECT user_id,recent_company,position,MAX(start_year) as start_year,end_year 
FROM work 
group by user_id 
order by user_id) uw ON u.user_id =uw.user_id
```

Result of my query for 1st recent company on start year basis:

```
user_id  First_name  Last_name     recent_company1   
  1        AAA         BBB            ABC                          
  2        PPP         QQQ            XYZ                           
  3        SSS         RRR            QRS             

position1    start_year1    end_year1
   CCC         2014           2015
   TTT         2008           2009
   ZZZ         2001           2002
```

Required Output for both 1st and 2nd recent company on start_year basis:

```
user_id  First_name  Last_name   recent_company1   position1    
  1        AAA         BBB          ABC             CCC                 
  2        PPP         QQQ          XYZ             TTT                
  3        SSS         RRR          QRS             ZZZ                 

start_year1    end_year1
    2014         2015
    2008         2009
    2001         2002

   recent_company2   position2   start_year2    end_year2
      PQR               DDD         2013          2014
      IJK               MMM         2005          2008
      NULL              NULL        NULL          NULL
```

Comment: Is there possibility to iterate result ?

Answer (score -1):

i have done the same thing using the php script.
I am also looking for the answer using sql query .. so that it can be done within the sql query ..

```
  function tag_listing() {
    echo 'Row Number' . ',' . 'TagID' . ',' . 'Status' . ',' . 'UserName' . ',' . 'Country' . ',' . 'PostCode' . ',';
    $array = array('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh', 'Eighth', 'Ninth', 'Tenth');
    $entityName = "Allocation Entity";
    $entity_type = "Entity Type";
    $allocDate = "Allocation Date";
    $sqlCount = "SELECT count(*) as total from tag_allocation  group by id_tag HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";
    $countQuery = $this->db->query($sqlCount);
    foreach ($countQuery->result() as $NewTotal) {
        $resRows = $NewTotal->total;
        $item = array_slice($array, 0, $resRows);
        foreach ($item as $items) {
            echo $items . ' ' . $entityName . ',';
            echo $items . ' ' . $entity_type . ',';
            echo $items . ' ' . $allocDate . ',';
        }
        break;
    }
    $query = $this->db->query("select  id_tag_id, IT.id_tag, ITS.status,
    CASE WHEN firstname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) END as Username,
    CASE WHEN U.country IS NULL THEN '' ELSE U.country END as Country,
    CASE WHEN U.postcode IS NULL THEN '' ELSE U.postcode END as postcode,
    CASE WHEN E.entity_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE E.entity_name END as entity_name,
    ET.entity_type, TA.allocation_date, TA.allocation_type from id_tag IT
    INNER JOIN id_tag_status ITS ON IT.id_tag_status_id = ITS.id_tag_status_id
    RIGHT JOIN tag_allocation TA ON IT.id_tag = TA.id_tag
    INNER JOIN entity_type ET ON ET.entity_type_id = TA.allocation_type
    LEFT JOIN allocation_entity E ON E.entity_id = TA.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN user U ON U.user_id = IT.user_id
    order by IT.id_tag, TA.allocation_date asc        ");
    $IDTAG = '';
    $rowCount = 0;
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $newID = $row->id_tag;
        if ($IDTAG != $newID) {
            echo "\r\n";
        }
        if ($IDTAG == $newID) {
            echo $entityName = $row->entity_name . ',' . $entityType = $row->entity_type . ',' . $allocationDate = $row->allocation_date . ',';
        } else {
            $rowCount = $rowCount + 1;
            $IDTAG = $row->id_tag;
            echo $rowCount . ',' . $idTag = $row->id_tag . ',' . $status = $row->status . ',' . $Username = $row->Username . ',' . $Country = $row->Country . ',' . $postcode = $row->postcode . ',' . $entityName = $row->entity_name . ',' . $entityType = $row->entity_type . ',' . $allocationDate = $row->allocation_date . ',';
        }
    }
    exit();
}
```

Hope it helps .. try this and you will get it .. 
Thank you ...